# TypeError: this.state.tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am getting the following error in my code. Can you please help me to understand the issue. I have included my page component and task list component.

*TypeError: this.state.tasks.map is not a function*

**Page Show.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TasksList from './TasksList';

export default class Show extends Component {

    constructor(props)  {
        super(props);
        this.state = {tasks: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
            axios.post('http://mohamed-bouhlel.com/p5/todolist/todophp/show.php')
            .then(response => { 
                this.setState({ tasks: response.data });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }

        tasksList(){
            return this.state.tasks.map(function(object,i){
                return <TasksList obj = {object} key={i} />;
            });
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.tasksList() }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Page TasksList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TasksList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.obj.task}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `response.data` may not be an array. Have you tried logging/debugger to see what its shape is?

Comment: Can you log `response.data` in the first then block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `GET` request and correct protocol (https vs http) seems to resolve the issue.

```
axios.get("https://mohamed-bouhlel.com/p5/todolist/todophp/show.php")
```

[image: Edit admiring-frog-5q2x6]

Answer (score 0):

Response.data is not an array and basically you can't call map on a non-array.
I suggest `console.log(response.data)` to check the data type.

And I guess maybe you're doing a `axios.post` instead of a correct `axios.get`. log the `response.data` and you'll find out.

Comment: Have you actually checked out the [url](https://mohamed-bouhlel.com/p5/todolist/todophp/show.php)? it returns an array of objects.

Comment: @awran5 yes. that's why I told him to use `axios.get` instead of `axios.post`.